# Cardinality of nested infinite subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $A$ and $C$ be infinite sets, with $C \subset A$, and suppose $|A|=|C|$. Now suppose there exists a set $B$ such that $C \subset B \subset A$.

Intuitively, $A$ and $B$ should have the same cardinality. I'm sure the proof is ridiculously easy but I haven't been able to find it. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem ?

Comment: why is nested in quotes? the sets are nested

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown thank you. Maybe it wasn't so trivial after all?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown You should give basically that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody's answered this one yet, as Lord Shark suggests, the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem makes short work of this. Inclusion is an injective map $B\to A,$ whereas composing the inclusion $C\to B$ with the bijection $A\to C$ that exists by assumption gives an injective map $A\to B.$

Comment: It might be of some interest that this fact is equivalent to the Schröder-Bernstein theorem. To prove the converse, suppose we have injective maps $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$. Then consider the nested sets $X\supseteq g(Y)\supseteq g(f(X))$, note that we have a bijection $gf$ from$X$ to $g(f(X))$, infer that there's a bijection from $X$ to $g(Y)$, and compose that  with $g^{-1}$ to get a bijection from $X$ to $Y$.